# Android layout - how to draw a hole in a rectangle

Tags: java, android, layout

I need to create a rounded rectangle with a semi-circular section cut out of the bottom of it - how do I go about this? Sorry for the extremely open ended question - I just have no idea where to start looking to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PorterDuffXfermodes...

```
Paint clear = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
clear.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
```

Then just draw with this paint.

And for the semi circular thing, check out `canvas.drawArc()` and pathes.